# Получить и обработать данные с экрана

Tags: c++, c

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по следующему вопросу.

Имеется игра (возьмём в пример любую мобу - dota, hots). В момент загрузки матча выводятся данные по игрокам, которые будут принимать участие в игре (прикрепление).

Собственно, сама задача - получить некоторые данные (ники игроков) с загрузочного экрана и записать данные в *txt файл.

Вероятно, что в процессе выполнения кода создаётся "скриншот", далее, вырезаются необходимые данные через позиционирование X/Y (расположение ников игроков на экране всегда имеет фиксированное значение), и далее выполняется сохранение данных в *txt файл, например.

К чему всё. Единожды приметил на одном стриме лаунчен по игре StarCraft (первая часть), там, во время игры, сверху экрана выводилась информация по тем игрокам, что участвуют в матче, пример: "Игрок 1 vs Игрок 2". Данные, конечно же, заносились не вручную, самим лаунчером. Идея понравилось, пожелал применить нечто схожее, но на иные игры.

Данный вопрос задаётся не с целью получения какого-либо кода-решения, - с целью получить подсказку, на каком языке программирования возможно реализовать данную задачу (и вообще, возможно ли).

[image]

Comment: Данные на экране в графическом виде, что бы их конвертировать в нормальные данные надо применять технологии распознавания текста, что тяжеловесно и не дает 100% гарантии достоверности. Думаю приведенный ниже ответ примерно то что вам нужно, проще найти в памяти игры или в ее сетевом трафике

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Значит это и будет оптимальным вариантом решения. Возможно лишь получить уточнение, какой язык следует начать изучать, чтобы разобраться с данной задачей в некотором будущем?

Comment: Указанные в задачи теги C, C++ именно то, что надо, они наиболее близки к "железу" из языков высокого уровня

Comment: Спасибо большое за рекомендации :)

Answer (score 1):

Начать стоило бы с метода ArtMoney. Авось данные лежат всегда по одному и тому же адресу, откуда их можно стянуть. Это может оказаться проще, чем изобретать техническое зрение.

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендацию, прислушиваюсь!

Comment: Пройдите туториал Cheat Engine. Базовый адрес в памяти при каждом перезапуске для переменных не факт, что будет сохраняться. А вот указатель или указатель-на-указатель уже более статичная вещь :)

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендацию! Обязательно прислушаюсь :)